# What is the main use of injecting service into run method instead of controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

If you inject **service/factory** inside the run function as dependency means it executes **priority** from normal order. It means service/factory runs before directive setup. 
Normal order is

- app config
- app run
- directive setup
- directive compile
- (app controller dependencies)

  - service
  - factory
- app controller
- filter
- directive linking

My question is why we used to inject service in run function? What is the benefit?

Answer (score 2):

The benefit could be with **ui-router** or other stateRouter. Here is the code example:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, krozAuthService) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',  function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

        if (krozAuthService.roleAccess[state] &&
            krozAuthService.roleAccess[state] === 'DISABLED'){
          e.preventDefault();
          return;
        }
```

This is from authentication part of application which was wrote by me. krozAuth is the **service** for authentication and it have information about role of currently logged in user. So, logged in user WILL NOT be able to go to the state and HTML page WILL NOT be loaded ***in case of user have no rights for that***.

Answer (score 0):

From [AngularJS docs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/ce669edfa14dc7eb7c389d2f82c9c98399a9009b/docs/content/guide/module.ngdoc):

> Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run block is the code which
>   needs to run to kickstart the application. It is executed after all of the service have been
>   configured and the injector has been created. Run blocks typically contain code which is hard
>   to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated modules, so that they can be
>   ignored in the unit-tests.

Most examples available on the internet mention Authentication as one of it's main uses.

Comment: Dude, I'm asking about the benefits, not the features of the run method.

Comment: Which are described on the features. The answer you chose is outdated and is not the best way to do authorization control anymore. @Arul

Comment: Ok. What is the difference injecting a service in the controller as well as the run method?@tiagodws

Comment: A controller is attached to a component or a directive, and will only be executed when one of those is instantiated. If you navigate to a state, only the respective controllers from the views on that state will get executed.

The run method, instead, will get executed when the module is created. If you need, for example, to get all the translations needed for a module and you have a service for that, you can't do it in a .config method, because you still don't have your instance injections (service), and doing it in a controller would create a dependency with the respective view. @Arul